# How to distinguish a 'move' drag operation from a copy on OSX

Tags: macos, qt

In Windows you can distinguish the 'move' drag operation from a 'copy' drag operation by checking if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed. How can I do the same thing on OSX? I'm using the Qt framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `QDropEvent`, using keyboardModifiers() function is a good way to distinguish the 'move' drag operation from a 'copy' drag operation